# Wildfly vs Payara(Glassfish)

Tags: веб-сервер, glassfish, wildfly, payara

После пойманного бага в GlassFish узнал, что поддержка его свободной версии сходит на нет. Мне предложили Payara для замены, позже прочел несколько сравнений GF и WildFly, где, если верить авторам, WildFly выходит победителем.

Хотелось бы услышать ваши мнения в виде "за/против" этих двух серверов, какие могут возникнуть сложности при работе с тем или иным сервером? Судя ответам в поисковиках, Payara не такой уж и популярный, но стоит ли надеяться на его продолжительную поддержку?

Comment: Всё относительно. Я вот GF забросил c релиза 4 версии, не найдя способа одолеть баги. А Вы не замечали в нём недостатка 2 года. Попробуйте сами. При переходе на другой сервер придётся осваивать особенности замены. На Wildfly документация очень скудная и даже большой брат JBoss не помогает - единственный (но вполне преодолимый как по мне) недостаток Wildfly vs GF. Множество подсистем у них, кстати, одинаковые (с точностью до версии)

Comment: как такое можно утверждать? Хотя, с какой стороны посмотреть, если  год назад я не знал о его существовании, то да. Не замечал!

Comment: У Вас теперь есть прекрасная возможность заценить payara и рассказать всем как оно. Про него тоже никто не знал. Сам бы попробывал, но Wildfly вполне устраивает и пока так, смысла куда-то дёргаться нет. А Вам на перепутье ещё можно.

Comment: Кстати, если вдруг ничего из того, что из javaee web profile делает javaee full profile не нужно, то выбор халявного сервера вообще никак не ограничен. У самого уже сомнения, может не стоило бросать spring ради javaee.